# Consulta SQL + PHP: pegar apenas dados do ano atual desde Janeiro até Hoje?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Preciso do retorno de dados entre 01/anoAtual até o dia atual. Mas ainda não sou muito familiarizada com SQL e PHP date();

Eis o trecho do código:

```
$startMP = date('Y');

'BETWEEN '{$startMP} 00:00:00' AND NOW()'
```

Comment: Utilize a função YEAR() aplicada à sua data e verifique se é igual a YEAR(NOW()).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem várias formas de resolver essa questão, a mais simples seria a que foi sugerida no comentário

```
SELECT * from minha_tabela WHERE year(campo_data) = YEAR(now)
```

Outras formas de fazer:

```
SELECT * FROM minha_tabela  WHERE campo_data >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-01-01');

SELECT * FROM minha_tabela  WHERE campo_data >= MAKEDATE(year(now()),1);
```

Comment: Isso mesmo, usei a segunda opção das 3 que você disponibilizou! Obrigada :)

Answer (score -1):

Poderia usar um cast para "Forçar" o operador BETWEEN a usar o conteúdo da variável $startMP como uma data no MySQL.

```html
BETWEEN CAST('{$startMp}' AS DATE) AND CAST(NOW() AS DATE);
```

Se não funcionar na segunda condição, troca "NOW()" por uma data PHP e faz o Cast novamente.

Abraços!